# basic wav data chunk

Tags: audio, wav

I have a question about the basic wav file data chunk.

I know that each 2 bytes in the data chunk section represent mono sound and left and right channel is alternately stored, but I still have no idea how to understand the 2 byte value.

Is it high and low?

- value 0000 => lowest?
- value FFFF => highest?
- value 8FFF => no sound?

If so, when I want to reduce volume 50%, is all I have to do just classfy low and high 
and divive by 2?

Comment: I've rephrased your question to make it a little more readable. Good question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAV files can contain samples at different bit depths and encodings, but one of the most commonly used is 16 bit PCM. With 16 bit PCM data in a WAV file, each two bytes should be interpreted as a short (i.e. a signed, two-byte number). In WAV files, the samples are always "little-endian". If you tag your question with a language, someone might be able to provide some simple sample code. In C/C++, you would cast your array of data read from the file into a (short *), allowing you to easily access each sample.

To answer the second part of your question, yes you can reduce the volume by halving the value of each sample.

Comment: i'm trying to get all positive and negative component of a signal from raw wav audio using below code...

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9937987..am i doing correct??

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding seems fine. The only thing I can think to say is one byte will be a most significant byte, and one will be least significant. Other than that, you seem spot on.

And your question is fine (In my opinion anyway!) Although more useful answers might be gotten if you were to ask a specific programming question, but I can see how that might not be possible.

Comment: can I ask you which one is least significant byte and why?